# Можно ли применить метод __repr__ к классу, а не к его экземплярам?

Tags: python, классы

```
class test():
    c = 0
    def __init__ (self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        test.c += self.a * self.b
    @classmethod
    def __repr__ (cls):
        return "{}".format(cls.c)

p_1 = test(10, 20)
p_2 = test(5, 6)
print (test) # должно быть 230
```

Answer (score 5):

```
class A(type):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.c)

class test(metaclass = A):
    c = 0
    def __init__ (self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        test.c += self.a * self.b

p_1 = test(10, 20)
p_2 = test(5, 6)
print(test)
```

Comment: Есть ли варианты без метаклассов?

Comment: @Molotoff возможно есть, но я не знаю